How to refresh stale data from RTK query?
Here's piece of my code. I added refetchOnMountOrArgChange and now I see how it fetches new data on network but the data from query is still stale and I get previous user data and that's why it exits because of role mismatch. Adding providesTags and invalidatesTags didn't help either.
const ProtectedRoute = ({ redirectPath = '/', role }: IProtectedRouteProps) => {
    const exit = () => {
        dispatch(logout());
        navigate(redirectPath, { replace: true });
    };

    const { data, // STALE DATA
 isError, isLoading} = useGetUserDetailsQuery('userDetails', {
        refetchOnMountOrArgChange: true,
        pollingInterval: 30000
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isError) {
            exit();
        } else if (data && Object.keys(data).length > 0) {
            dispatch(setCredentials(data));
            const userRole = data?.organization?.role;
            if (userRole && role && userRole !== role) {
                exit();
            }
        }
    }, [data, isError, role]);

    return <div>Protected Content</div>;
};

export default ProtectedRoute;


Here's my base api
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';
import { baseApiUrl } from 'configs/env-exports';

export const baseApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'api',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
        // base url of backend API
        baseUrl: baseApiUrl,
        prepareHeaders: (headers) => {
            const token = localStorage.getItem('userToken');
            if (token) {
                headers.set('authorization', token);
                return headers;
            }
        },
    }),
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        getUserDetails: builder.query({
            query: () => ({
                url: 'api/v1/account/info',
                method: 'GET',
            }),
        }),
        
    }),
});

export const {
    useGetUserDetailsQuery,
} = baseApi;

and my slice which i minimized removing unnecessary parts
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

// initialize userToken from local storage
export const userToken = localStorage.getItem('userToken')
    ? localStorage.getItem('userToken')
    : null;

export type IUserInfo = null | {
    id: number;
    login: string;
    name: string;
    notifications: {
        id: number;
        type: string;
        value: string;
    }[];
    organization: {
        name: string;
        address: string;
        role: string;
    };
};

type AuthApiState = {
    userInfo: IUserInfo;
    userToken: null | string;
    userRole: null | string;
};

const initialState: AuthApiState = {
    userInfo: null,
    userToken,
    userRole: null,
};

const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'auth',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        logout: (state) => {
            state.userToken = null;
            state.userInfo = null;
            state.userRole = null;
            localStorage.removeItem('userToken');
        },
        setCredentials: (state, { payload }) => {
            state.userInfo = payload;
            state.userRole = payload?.organization?.role;
        },
    },
});

export const { logout, setCredentials } = authSlice.actions;


What stale data and what authorization process are you referring to? Please [edit] to clarify the issue you face in clearer detail and include a [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with.

What does useGetUserDetailsQuery do that it is returning stale query data? How do you know it's stale? FWIW we probably need to see your API slice defining this endpoint and any additional "authorization" code/logic that handles it. If the data is stale in the consuming UI, then you need to look upstream at the source to see where/how/why it might be stale.

Because if I call my api without rtk it works fine, besides I already explained that network response provides fresh data which isn't reflected in data from query.

"Because if I call my api without rtk it works fine" - What does your API slice do differently from calling the endpoint directly somewhere? "besides I already explained that network response provides fresh data which isn't reflected in data from query" Ok, but you have really only stated your hook returns stale data and haven't shared the logic behind it. We can't address issues in code we can't see, which is why a [mcve] was requested.

Not much here. useGetUserDetailsQuery only calls a "api/v1/account/info" and returns the cached response. How exactly is it stale? Tag invalidation only works when you've mutations that invalidate tags queries provide. You've only the single query though.

When I logout I want my data from query to be null or undefined instead of showing cached response, how can I achieve it?

So you want this query endpoint to be polled every 5 minutes, no matter what, and after the user logs out, i.e. the logout action is dispatch, for the query cache to be cleared/reset/etc?

Yes. Because the query cache stays even when i logout and login under different user/account.


When I logout I want my data from query to be null or undefined instead of showing cached response

You could dispatch the resetApiState action to:

manually reset the api state completely. This will immediately remove
all existing cache entries, and all queries will be considered
'uninitialized'.

Note however the docs also warn:

Note that hooks also track state in local component state and might not fully be reset by resetApiState.

I suspect there are possible edge cases where this happens, but in most cases I've seen it just works and clears the API slice state.
I suggest converting your logout action into a Thunk so that it can also dispatch additional actions where the authSlice can handle the action in its extraReducers. Since reducer functions are to be considered pure functions the updating of localStorage should be moved out of the reducer anyway.
Example:
import { createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { baseApi } from '../path/to/baseApi';

export const logout = createAsyncThunk(
  "auth/logout",
  (_, { dispatch }) => {
    localStorage.removeItem('userToken');
    dispatch(baseApi.util.resetApiState());
  }
);

import { createSlice, isAnyOf, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { logout } from '../path/to/logout';

...

const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'auth',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setCredentials: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.userInfo = payload;
      state.userRole = payload?.organization?.role;
    },
  },
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder.addMatcher(
      isAnyOf(logout.fulfilled, logout.rejected),
      (state) => {
        state.userToken = null;
        state.userInfo = null;
        state.userRole = null;
    }
    );
  },
});

export const { setCredentials } = authSlice.actions;

export default authSlice.reducer;

I also would like to point out that your getUserDetails endpoint doesn't consume any arguments
getUserDetails: builder.query({
  query: (/* no argument */) => ({
    url: 'api/v1/account/info',
    method: 'GET',
  }),
}),

So passing any value to query hooks is irrelevant. Typically you'd just pass nothing, or just undefined in the case that you need to pass the second options argument.
const {
  data,
  isError,
  isLoading
} = useGetUserDetailsQuery(
  undefined, // no argument
  {
    refetchOnMountOrArgChange: true,
    pollingInterval: 30000
  }
);

